# Date comparison not taking timezone into account

Tags: laravel, date, timezone, php-carbon

I'm trying to compare a start date of an event resource I have with the `now` date. All dates are being stored as UTC and then the timezone is set according to the user's timezone.

But when I compare the dates the difference is always the same regardless of the timezone I set. It's always being evaluated as UTC. So for instance when I set

```
$now = Carbon::now()->tz($profileTimezone);
```

And then try to compare it with another date

```
$difference = $now->diffInHours($event->starts_at));
```

It's always returning the same difference object with the same values regardless of the timezone I set for `now`. Shouldn't the difference in `hours`, for example, change when `now` is in a different timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running the `tz` method it will convert the datetime object to that timezone. Meaning if you change now to a timezone which is 1 hour behind from the current timezone, it will subtract that hour from the time.

What you are looking for is the method `shiftTimezone`, that one will change the timezone without changing the time also.

```
Carbon::now();
// 2019-07-29 12:53:29.575769 UTC (+00:00)

Carbon::now()->shiftTimezone('Asia/Phnom_Penh');
// 2019-07-29 12:53:29.572207 Asia/Phnom_Penh (+07:00)

Carbon::now()->tz('Asia/Phnom_Penh');
// 2019-07-29 19:53:29.575776 Asia/Phnom_Penh (+07:00)
```